# Get the user role in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, asp.net-identity

How can I get the User Role in code behind? For example

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

will get me the UserId. But how can I get the role?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you use session?

Comment: [Roles.GetRolesForUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ak75t41(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get list of user's roles (Return Roles as a list):

**C#:**

```
string strUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
UserManager userManager = new UserManager();
foreach (object roleName in userManager.GetRoles(strUserId)) {
    roleName = roleName;
    lblMsg.Text += roleName;
}
```

**VB:**

```
Dim strUserId As String = User.Identity.GetUserId
Dim userManager As New UserManager
For Each roleName In userManager.GetRoles(strUserId)
    lblMsg.Text += roleName
Next
```

And if you want to check if the user is in a specific role or not (Return as a Boolean):

**C#:**

```
string strUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
UserManager userManager = new UserManager();
lblMsg.Text = userManager.IsInRole(strUserId, "Admin");
```

**VB:**

```
Dim strUserId As String = User.Identity.GetUserId
Dim userManager As New UserManager
lblMsg.Text = userManager.IsInRole(strUserId, "Admin")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the Roles.GetRolesForUser Method for getting the roles of the currently logged-on user.

**MSDN-link**

[Roles.GetRolesForUser Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ak75t41(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Example:** (taken from msdn)

```
string[] rolesArray;

public void Page_Load()
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    // Bind roles to GridView.

    try
    {
      rolesArray = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
    }
    catch (HttpException e)
    {
      Msg.Text = "There is no current logged on user.";
      return;
    }
  }
}
```